# Block updates in a table SQLite Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

I wish to know if there a way to block updates in a table from SQLite android database. I am developing an app. Certain table has two foreign keys that are a unique constraint. Once inserted a row this row should not be updated. It can be only deleted if necessary. Does make sense for you? Can I create my tables in this way? Do you know a better way to code this?

Comment: Use a [trigger](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_triggers.htm)

Comment: not sure why you need a table constraint for this. just make sure you never call `update` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could put a [trigger](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtrigger.html) on the table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER block_MyTable_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON MyTable
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "updates not allowed");
END;
```

Comment: Thanks CL. The trigger works fine! See my statements in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is my create table and trigger statements:

```
CREATE TABLE 
IF NOT EXISTS movie (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    adult INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    backdrop_path TEXT, 
    belongs_to_collection INTEGER, 
    budget INTEGER,
    homepage TEXT, 
    imdb_id TEXT, 
    original_language TEXT NOT NULL, 
    original_title TEXT NOT NULL, 
    overview TEXT NOT NULL, 
    popularity REAL NOT NULL, 
    poster_path TEXT NOT NULL, 
    release_date TEXT NOT NULL, 
    revenue INTEGER, 
    runtime INTEGER, 
    status TEXT, 
    tagline TEXT, 
    title TEXT NOT NULL, 
    video TEXT NOT NULL, 
    vote_average REAL NOT NULL, 
    vote_count INTEGER NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE 
IF NOT EXISTS genre (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    name TEXT NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE 
IF NOT EXISTS movie_genre (
    _id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
    movie_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    genre_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        FOREIGN KEY ( movie_id) REFERENCES movie(_id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT, 
        FOREIGN KEY ( genre_id) REFERENCES genre(_id) ON UPDATE RESTRICT, 
        CONSTRAINT contrstraint_movie_genre_unique 
            UNIQUE (movie_id, genre_id) ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK);

CREATE TRIGGER 
IF NOT EXISTS triger_movie_genre_update 
    BEFORE 
        UPDATE OF movie_id, genre_id ON movie_genre 
            BEGIN 
                SELECT RAISE(FAIL, "UPDATES NOT ALLOWED") 
            END;
```

This triggers works fine. Thanks!